# How to solve $\frac{n}{\theta} - \sum_{i = 1}^n{\frac{(x_i - 1)}{1 - \theta}} = 0$ for $\theta$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I cannot see how the following expression could be solved for $\theta$:
$$
\frac{n}{\theta} - \sum_{i = 1}^n{\frac{(x_i - 1)}{1 - \theta}} = 0
$$
Here is what I have tried:
\begin{align}
    &\frac{n}{\theta} - \sum_{i = 1}^n{\frac{(x_i - 1)}{1 - \theta}} = 0\\
    &\frac{n}{\theta} = \sum_{i = 1}^n{\frac{(x_i - 1)}{1 - \theta}}\\
    &\frac{n}{\theta} = \frac{1}{1-\theta}\sum_{i = 1}^n{(x_i - 1)}\\
    &n\frac{(1-\theta)}{\theta} = \sum_{i = 1}^n{(x_i - 1)}\\
    &\frac{(1-\theta)}{\theta} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n{(x_i - 1)}\\
\end{align}
Something must be wrong - can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.  A couple more steps:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\theta}-\frac{\theta}{\theta} &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1\\
\frac{1}{\theta}-1 &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - 1\\
\frac{1}{\theta} &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\\
\theta &= \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}
\end{align}

Comment: How did you get from step 2 to 3? :)

Comment: Take reciprocals of both sides.  Don't be that guy. :)

Comment: Roger that - but how did you then remove the (-1) which is within the sigma from the right side by adding one to the right side? Just wanna make sure I get it :)))

Comment: I added one more step to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

You are extremely close to being done. Call

$$X=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-1)$$

Then we are solving

$$\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}=X$$

$$1-\theta=X\theta$$

$$1=X\theta+\theta$$

$$1=\theta(X+1)$$

$$\theta=\frac{1}{X+1}$$

Thus,

$$\theta=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-1)}$$